# How can I modify my regular expression to test only the characters in a string that appear before alphanumeric characters appear?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to test a string that is a file path with a regular expression, and I want the test of the regex to return true if and only if the characters before the file name (which are alphanumeric characters only) are `./` or `./../`.  My issue is that if the path contains a directory such as `./../../`, the test returns true because the directory begins with `./`.

I figure that if I test for an exact match on only the characters that appear *before* any alphanumeric characters, I can eliminate this problem, but I don't know how to do this.

Code:

```
function validPath(path) {
   if (!/^(\.\/|\.\/\.\.\/)/.test(path)) {
      path = "ERROR" //the path is not valid if ERROR is returned
   }

   return path;      //the path is valid if the path is returned
}
```

I expect the output of `validPath('./../../index.html')` to be `ERROR`, but the output is `./../../index.html`

Comment: Are the alphanumeric characters that start the file name ASCII only?

Comment: @RayToal yes, they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that all file names begin with ascii letters or digits or underscores you can extend your regex to say that the next character after the `./` or `./../` must be one of the leading characters of a file name:

```
if (!/^(\.\/|\.\/\.\.\/)\w/.test(path)) {
```

Here `\w` stands for `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

If you wish to accept filenames that begin with a dot or non-ASCII letters, you'll have more work to do.

JavaScript regexes do not natively handle non-ASCII letters, but you can get a third party regex engine to do so.

Another approach is to say

```
if (!/^(\.\/|\.\/\.\.\/)[^.]/.test(path)) {
```

which means you don't want the first character after the `./` or `./../` to be another dot. This will handle filenames with non-ASCII letters, but it won't pick up hidden files that begin with a dot.

Hope that gets you closer!